# Tool Tip obscures button

Tags: wxwidgets

I want to pop up a tool tip when mouse moves over button, to explain what will happen if the user clicks on the button.

This code seems to do the job ( except for a big snag )

```
wxHelpProvider::Set(new wxSimpleHelpProvider);

...

btnDisplay = new wxButton( this, -1,
                           "DISPLAY", wxPoint(10,35));
btnDisplay->SetHelpText("Click to display this dimension");
btnDisplay->Bind( wxEVT_ENTER_WINDOW, &cHiddenDimensionPanel::OnDisplayHelp, this );

...

void cHiddenDimensionPanel::OnDisplayHelp(wxMouseEvent& event)
{
wxHelpProvider::Get()->ShowHelp((wxWindowBase*)event.GetEventObject());
}
```

[image]

The snag is that the tooltip obscures the button!  If I click on it, the tool tip vanishes for a moment, but immediately pops back up.  It is not possible to click the button under the tooltip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using the `SetToolTip(const wxString &tipString)` method, and letting wx handle showing/hiding the tooltip - not re-appropriating the `HelpText` property and manually managing the tooltip display.